# Word (Office 365) - "autofit to content" does not give the table with the shortest height

Tags: microsoft-word

Lately I have noticed that in Word (Office 365), doing "autofit to content" does not give the table with the shortest height. I am able to further adjust column widths to make the table shorter. Why? What logic is used behind "autofit to content" for tables in Word.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Can you provide some screenshots to show the behavior you expect vs. the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: There may be some padding to make everything look nice

Comment: "autofit to content" only handles columns data content, not headers content. Is that your problem?